# How can I run test scenario in chrome using browser cache in karate?

Tags: karate

I am testing a scenario in which I have to run chrome with cache so how can I do that as by default it launches browser without any cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a normal requirement, but we have an option to set the `userDataDir`, here below is a screenshot [from the documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core):

[image]

So if you know the path of a directory that exists, you can pass that. That said, maybe the correct testing strategy is to make a call 2 times and ensure that the second call is being cached. But some investigation may be required.

Comment: I tried using this. It works pretty fine just one doubt can we had a option to provide dynamic path in that like we have classpath in karate so that it does not have any system dependency. Or any other alternative for that if its possible ?

Comment: sorry, trying to be generic across all systems is not something we want to do in karate, maybe you will be interested to contribute code. I suggest don't over-engineer this, why don't you use config to set this differently if needed

Comment: just a reminder that if you set `userDataDir: null` it *will* default to the chrome system install. if that doesn't work - maybe karate is not the right tool for you, all the best :)

Comment: sorry mistakenly deleted comment try to edit it.userDataDir: null solves my issue. Thanks.